# What's the easiest way to rename a directory that has content in Java?

Tags: java

`File`'s `renameTo` method only works when the directory is empty. What's the easiest way to make it work besides making a new directory and copying the old directory's contents into it?

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveDirectory(java.io.File,%20java.io.File)

Comment: `new File("x").renameTo(new File("y"))` will rename folder `x` to `y`, even if it has files in it, so your statement that it *"only works when the directory is empty"* is wrong.

Comment: @Andreas nope. when I do this on windows nothing happens.

Comment: I just did it in Windows.

Comment: [`Files.move`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...))? Same issues a bit, otherwise `copy` is advised.

Comment: @Andreas so did I, and it did not work.

Answer (score 5):

> `File`'s `renameTo` method only works when the directory is empty.

That is **incorrect**.

*Proof*

```
new File("x").mkdir();
new File("x\\file.txt").createNewFile();
new File("x").renameTo(new File("y"));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new File(".").list()));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new File("y").list()));
new File("y\\file.txt").delete();
new File("y").delete();
```

*Output (run on Windows)*

```
[.classpath, .project, .settings, lib, pom.xml, src, target, y]
[file.txt]
```

As can be seen, the folder `x` was renamed to `y`, even though it has a file named `file.txt` in it.

---

**UPDATE**

You should however use the newer `Files.move(Paths.get("x"), Paths.get("y"))` instead of `new File("x").renameTo(new File("y"))`.

Unlike `renameTo`, which simply returns `false` on failure, the `Files.move` method will throw exception explaining why it failed.

Since you likely didn't even check the return value of `renameTo` (like the code above doesn't), the new method help prevent silent ignore of failures.

Comment: I confirmed this answer.  It works fine for me too.  @hey_you, if this doesn't work for you, then there's something wrong with your system or there's something more going on that you aren't telling us.

Comment: (Maybe he is trying to move a directory between file systems ... which the docs say won't work.)

Comment: @StephenC Except OP said "rename", not "move". Big difference. If OP meant "move", OP should have used that word. The fact that some APIs use the same method for both is a different matter (e.g. how [`Files.move`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) is used to "move or rename a file").

Comment: It is not a different matter.  You are expecting the OP to use a precise distinction between "rename" and "move" when neither the Java APIs or typical OS command utilities make that clear distinction.  I agree though that the OP should explain properly what he is trying to do ... and the circumstances in which it is not working.